# Имеется три массива,как сделать так чтобы каждый массив выводился в новой строке

Tags: java

```
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread th1=new ThreadArray();
        Thread th2=new ThreadArray1();
        Thread  th3=new ThreadArray2();

th1.start();
th2.start();
th3.start();

Thread.sleep(10);

    }
}


class  ThreadArray extends  Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int array1[]=new int[3];
//

            for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
                array1[i]= (int) (Math.random());
                System.out.print("  Array1: "+array1[i]+" ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    class ThreadArray1 extends  Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int array2[] = new int[3];

            for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
                array2[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100);
                System.out.print("  Array2: "+array2[i]+" ");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }

        class ThreadArray2 extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int array3[] = new int[3];

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    array3[i] = (int) (Math.random());
                    System.out.print("  Array3: "+array3[i]+" ");

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Вывод:

> Array2: 91   Array1: 0   Array3: 0   Array2: 58   Array1: 0   Array3: 0   Array2: 31   Array1: 0   Array3: 0

Comment: В чем конкретно ваш вопрос состоит?

Comment: Надо три массива вывести одновременно(с использованием Thread).

Comment: @Gülşən хорошо, выводите.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Вот я с выводом и по меньше размером написала.Там каждый элемент массива выводится одновременно поэтому и вперемешку выводится,никак не могу аккуратно вывести:(

Comment: Так вы определитесь, вам всё-таки одновременно надо или по порядку. И если второй, то какой должен быть порядок - сначала один массив, потом другой, потом третий или в порядке возрастания/убывания элементов всех трёх массивов?

Comment: th1.start(); th1.join();
th2.start(); th2.join()
th3.start(); th3.join(); попробуйте так

Comment: @aleshka-batman thanks

Comment: @aleshka-batman А без join  можно как то?Потому что join ждет а мне надо чтоб как можно быстрее выполнялась.С join 43 мс  ,а без нее 1 мс.

Comment: добавьте блок синхронизации и введите свой монитор, но это тоже самое, что однопоточное выполнение, так же как и со стартами и джинами.

Comment: Как у вас за 1мс это может выполняться, если у вас Thread.sleep(100) стоит? И каким образом вы время замеряете? На таком размере массива, как в примере, замерить толком ничего нельзя.